# Как привести выходные данные в читабельный вид в delphi7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Тип данные extended
Пример вывода данных в эдит

```
eN.Text := FloatToStrF(N, ffGeneral, 4 ,4) ;
```

[image: в]

Answer (score 1):

Моя ошибка, так было бы правильно написать:

```
eN.Text := FloatToStrF(N, ffFixed, 12 ,4) ;
```

Если в `(N, ffFixed, A, B);` A>B  то кол-во выводимой информации без E будет равно A, если значение превышено, то остаток будет выводится через E.